# How to fit this javascript snippet into functions.php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, elementor

I have built a [website](http://www.naotech.com/he/) in a Wordpress using Elementor and GravityForms.
The website has a conditional form that opens new questions depending on your answers.
When I select any answer to the first question in the form the page automatically scrolls up to the top on any MOBILE device. The form is at the bottom of every page, as you can see here:
[image]

I found out that when I implement the snippet in the developers' console it solves the issue:

```
$(function(){ choice_1_2_0.click();})
```

At first, I tried to use the following HTML snippet using `<script></script>` tags both in body and footer (it's still there if you wish to inspect), but it didn't solve it for me.

Then, I tried to adjust this snippet and add it to the functions.php but I am not sure if it's correct:

```
function example_callback( $example ) {
// Maybe modify $example in some way.
echo "<script>$(function(){ choice_1_2_0.click();})
</script>";
}
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_anchor', example_callback);
```

Does anyone have any idea what I should do?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs you are not using `gform_confirmation_anchor` correctly.  The callback should return a `boolean` or an `integer`. Below are a few examples on how it is used: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_confirmation_anchor/

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_anchor', '__return_true' );

// or

add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_anchor', function () {
  return 20;
});
```

Here you can learn more about the callback return values: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_confirmation_anchor/#parameters

NOTE: Typically you should return values from `add_filter` rather than `echo` them.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that I have read this doc, and the problem doesn't occur when submitting the form, but when selecting the answer to the first question in that form.